# Is there a Micro-ORM by Microsoft?

Tags: .net, orm, dapper, micro-orm

The micro-ORM `Dapper` can populate an object from a database very easily without the need for other entity or class definitions.  Below is an example of `Dapper` code.

Is there an equivalent Microsoft package with the same functionality?

What is Microsoft's package that is closest to `Dapper`?

```
var stuff = db.Query<stuffclass>("select a,b,c from Foo where a = {0}", x)
```

Answer (score 5):

Enterprise Library 5.0 (and possibly earlier versions, I haven't checked) contains methods like [`ExecuteSqlStringAccessor<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff669814%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx), which I *believe* it does using the [`MapBuilder<TResult>` API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff667481%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx). I haven't done any work with this to comment on it's abilities / performance.

Another interesting option is to use something like a LINQ-to-SQL `DataContext` *without* telling it about a model, and just use the [`ExecuteQuery<TResult>` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109.aspx); since the type isn't known to the data-context, it *should* skip all the identity-manager/change-manager bits. However! It should be noted that one of the reasons we wrote dapper in the first place was because we were noticing performance problems (lost time, nothing to do with the query itself - looked like perhaps the metaprogramming cache layer).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think Dapper is closest to Simple.Data which will answer you question, but not sure if that will fit with what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out SQL Data (http://sqldata.codeplex.com).  It is quick like Dapper and very developer friendly.

(Disclosure - I am the the author of SQL Data)